# Select locations of all occurences of a sub-string in a string

Tags: mysql, replace

I am trying to get all the occurrences of a sub-string in a database field and the location of the next index after each. What I have done so far is to get the first occurrence and the location of the next string after it as following:

```
SELECT dataset.id,
       SUBSTRING(dataset.text, LOCATE('XXXX', dataset.text) + LENGTH('XXXX')) 
FROM datatable as dataset
```

any help please to get all occurrences ??

Comment: can you give example on what you want?

Comment: ok @John Woo, let at the following text:
{The second str returns the str of the first occurrence of str substr in string str}

I want to search for the indexes of the word "str" in the above text, so the result shall be for example : 12, 29 ,53, 77

Comment: Do this with PHP or whatever. Databases are there to hold and/or get you the data. Nothing more.

Comment: @user1180376 . . . What are you trying to accomplish with this?  And, given that the number of columns are fixed, how do you intend to store the results?

Comment: I count six occurrences of `str` in your example text, but your example result only shows the locations of four.  You need to improve the problem specification; and, as others have said, there may be a better way to achieve your desired outcome if only we knew what you were trying to do.  See [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Dears @GordonLinoff 
I just want to build a query that will search for particular string, and to achieve what is the index for the next character coming after the occurrences of such string. OR at least the indexes of the occurrences, as I showed in the example above.
This will help me in some areas I am working on. 

For the second part, actually I don't have an idea how to store such results, that is what I am looking for :)

Comment: Dear @eggyal,
sorry for the mistake in the example above, yes the occurrences are 6.
Anyways if there is no way to solve such issue with query, I will try doing it with php.

Comment: You've only repeated the problem that you already defined.  The question really was, how does this problem fit into your wider needs?  How will it be used?  Perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help:

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION getpos(haystack VARCHAR(255), search VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ret VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE pos INT;
    SET ret = "";
    SET pos = LOCATE (search, haystack);
    WHILE (pos > 0) DO
        SET ret = CONCAT_WS (',', ret, pos);
        SET pos = LOCATE (search, haystack, pos+1); 
    END WHILE;
    RETURN ret;
END//
```

Then do the select:

```
SELECT dataset.id, getpos (dataset.text, 'XXXX') FROM datatable as dataset
```